# Styles Lost in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Recently I've been working on a decent size project (at least for me), and I was just delegated the task of browser testing, all is fine except for IE. Just some of the styles are missing, like its picking and choosing which ones it wants, but by not loading those certain styles, its breaking a lot of the jquery. Are there known issues with this? What are the fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that on this website, we have 35 stylesheets, and the following conditions in IE are true.

If you have more than 31 `<style>` tags, only the first 31 will be compiled. Any beyond that will be ignored, with no warning from the web console.

Only the first 4095 style rules will be computed, anything after that will be ignored.

Stylesheets using `@import` nested more than 3 deep, will be ignored.

An easy fix for this is reducing your stylesheets into one stylesheet before the page loads with a server-side script.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Also, IE can cache your style sheets.  I've been driven nuts today by a CSS problem, where my new classes were not being taken up by the controls.  IE had cached an old version of the main CSS file.  I found out using F12 Developer Tools in IE, which has a CSS tab that will show you all of the styles that have loaded - I had old styles in memory, and no new styles.  IE, you piece of art...